# display the dynamic selection list when the page loads

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

i am working with jsp. i have a dynamic selection list. 
The user selects an option(GSM/CDMA) from the 1st selection list and the options in the second selection list change accordingly. The issue i'm facing is that when the page loads initially, it shows three lists "service" "gsmservice" and "cdmaservice".(it should only show two selection lists. 1st for gsm/cdma and the second one has to change dynamilcally) Although when the user selects an option out of GSM or CDMA then it works absolutely fine. but initially it shows both the selection lists which otherwise should be dynamic.
Below is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function optionsChange(){   
        var service = document.getElementById("service").value;
        if(service == 'GSM'){   
            document.getElementById("cdmaService").value= '';
            document.getElementById("cdmaService").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("gsmService").style.display = 'block';
        }else if(service == 'CDMA'){
            document.getElementById("gsmService").value= '';
            document.getElementById("cdmaService").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("gsmService").style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
</script>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <td style="color:white"> <font size="2"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SERVICE:</b></font> </td>
    <td><select id="service" name="service" onChange="javascript:optionsChange();">
            <option value="GSM">GSM</option>
            <option value="CDMA">CDMA</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr><td style="color:white"> <font size="2"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;VAS :</b></font> </td></tr>
<tr id="gsmService">
    <td><select name="gsmService" > 
            <option value="COMBO OFFER">COMBO OFFER</option>
            <option value="CRICKET">CRICKET</option>
            <option value="ASTRO">ASTRO</option>
        </select>   
    </td>
</tr>   
<tr id="cdmaService">
    <td><select name="cdmaService" >
        <option value="COMBO OFFER CDMA">COMBO OFFER CDMA</option>
        <option value="WIN THE DREAM">WIN THE DREAM</option>
        <option value="VOICE CHAT">VOICE CHAT</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what you want initially?

Comment: i want only two lists. "service" and the second one should be the dynamic selection list, showing options for either "gsm" or "cdma". which change according to the choice made in the 1st list(gsm or cdma).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want intially hide

```
<tr id="gsmService" style="display:none">

<tr id="cdmaService"  style="display:none">
```